# Question about definition of presheaf in Hartshorne

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

In the text of Algebraic geometry,Hartshorne defines presheaf like this.

[image]

And as the above text says,this can be rephrased by using category  word.

i.e. presheaf is contravariant functor from the category $Top(X)$ to the category $Ab$

($Top(X)$ is category whose objects are open subsets of X, and only morphisms are the inclusion maps,and $Ab$ is category of abelian groups,see image for details)

I have trouble in this definision.

**question**

If $F$ is contravariant functor from the category $Top(X)$ to the category $Ab$ ,how to show $F(∅)=0$.

This may be a trivial problem, but I have no idea so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See this question, its comments, and its answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149669/does-presheaf-send-the-empty-set-to-zero?rq=1